# eslint rule to disallow newline after equals in assignment (i.e. var foo =\n 42)

Tags: javascript, eslint, lint

Is there an eslint rule that will disallow, and hopefully fix code like this:

```
var foo =
  'why would you do this';
```

When it should be like this:

```
var bar = 'aahhhhh much better';
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is something you should do with `code formatter` not by `code linter`

You can simply use prettier or any other code fomratter as per your requirement

You can check here [`prettier playground`](https://prettier.io/playground/)

Comment: Prettier does do what I need, thank you. However I think the [explanatio](https://prettier.io/docs/en/comparison.html) about the difference between "formatting" and "linting" is odd. Especially when I think about using prettier for typescript. Typescript's linter tslint is being deprecated in favor of using its compiler for what they call "linting" and using eslint for what they call  "formatting".